# return statement in do-while

Tags: java, return, do-while

I have a code

```
  boolean playerTakesAHit() throws IOException {
  char ch = ' '; boolean hit=false;
  do{
   System.out.print("Hit or Stay: "); 
   System.out.flush();
   String playersDecision = keyboardInput.readLine(); 
   try {ch = playersDecision.charAt(0);
   } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
   if(ch == 'H' || ch == 'h') {
           return true;
       }
   if(ch == 'S' || ch == 's') {
           return false;
       }}
  } while(true);
```

What I want is this method will repeat while user hit H/h (return true) and immediately stop when user hit S/s. But when I call this method using :

```
 ...
 while(playerTakesAHit()) {
  System.out.println("Player Hit"); 
 }
 ...
```

I got something like this :

> Hit or Stay: h
>
> Hit or Stay: h
>
> Hit or Stay: s
>
> Hit or Stay: S
>
> Hit or  Stay:

It repeats asking Hit or Stay whatever the input from user.
Anybody knows where is my mistake?

Comment: Your if statement should be in the try block, not the catch section.

Comment: It will never break out of your `do...while` loop because it is always true.

Comment: @PeterJ thanks.
that's my solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  char ch = ' '; 
  boolean hit=false;
  do{
      System.out.print("Hit or Stay: "); 
      System.out.flush();
      String playersDecision = keyboardInput.readLine(); 
      try {
          ch = playersDecision.charAt(0);
      } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
          ch = ' '; //blank out
      }
      if(ch == 'H' || ch == 'h') {
         hit = true;
      }
    } while(!(ch == 'S' || ch == 's'));
    return hit;
```